# Blackberry Push Implementation and waiting for acknowledgement

Tags: blackberry, java-me, push-notification

I already implemented the first 4 steps of the push initiator for blackberry

1. Send a push request
2. BlackBerry service returns a response
3. BlackBerry service pushes data to an assigned, specific port on device
4. Device returns response to BlackBerry service

Now I am working on the following two steps but nothing has happened yet:

**5.    BlackBerry service forwards acknowledgement to content provider**

**6.    Read notification is returned to the BlackBerry service**

Does anyone know how to implement that? I provided a domain when filling out the request but how do I achieve connection between me and the blackberry servers and how long do I have to wait for their response?

Comment: These two steps are not related to BB development, since only the push initiator server and RIM infrastructure are involved.

Answer (score 1):

1. Actually your content provider send message to blackberry server and also specified the pin number of the device to which content provider want to send the message.
2. Your device automatically register with bb server if you have bb data service.
3. Your application is listening in the background on a particular port and your application also has particular app id that is provided by the rim.

So when content provider send message to bb server it also specify the app id and bb server has info about the port corresponding to this app id.and send message to the port of device whose pin is specified by the content provider.